# How to run `select` statement along with `where` using Lambda Expression in Asp .Net c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, lambda

I am running Select Statement along with Where condition but it gives me `0` data.

Code :

```
            public ActionResult ExportReport(int uid)
            {
                GridView gv = new GridView();
                gv.DataSource = db.tbl_demo.Where(x => x.UID == uid).
                                Select(x=> new { CustomerName = x.CUST_NAMER,ID=x.UID})
                                .FirstOrDefault();
             }
```

Comment: I assume "db" is some queryable such as an EF context. Typically this would imply that there are no records matching the "uid" you are trying to match against. Can you provide additional context to your question?

Comment: Aren't you missing gv.DataBind(); after you have assigned it datasource ?

Comment: please provide a [mcve]. You current example look incomplete.

Answer (score 1):

Your Code Statement has no problem
**Check Your DBContext Code Configuration**